# Why is $ref valid under the JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "definitions": {
        "person": {
          "properties": {
            "name": { "type": "string" }
          }
        },
        "employee": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/person",
            "properties": {
               "salary": { "type": "number" }
            }
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "Entry": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/employee"
        },
    },
}
```

And surprisingly, the following JSON is valid under the schema:

```
{
    "Entry": {
        "name": "John",
        "salary": "1234"
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how `$ref` works here? Why is this JSON valid?

-- EDIT --

I found that if I change

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"
```

to

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-05/schema"
```

it will work as expected, but only "draft-05" works; others like "draft-04" "draft-06" are not working.

Comment: Draft 5 isn't a valid draft.  It was never published. Rather it was merely a stepping stone to draft 6.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you think the instance should be invalid? It would help us explain why it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON Schema versions up to and including draft 7, when the `$ref` keyword is adjacent to any other keyword, the other keywords are ignored.

You can work around this by enclosing the `$ref` in an `allOf`:

```
...
        "employee": {
            "allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/person" } ],
            "properties": {
               "salary": { "type": "number" }
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned this only happens <= draft 7. I will use later versions.